# C# Regex - How to parse string for Swedish letters åäöÅÄÖ?

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse an HTML file for strings in this format:

```
<a href="/userinfo/userinfo.aspx?ID=305157" target="main">MyUsername</a> O22</td>
```

I want to retrieve the information where "305157", "MyUsername" and the first letter in "O22" (which can be either T, K or O).

I'm using this regex; `<a href="/userinfo/userinfo\.aspx\?ID=\d*" target="helgonmain">\w*</a> \w\d\d` and it works fine, as long as there aren't any åäöÅÄÖ's where the "\w" are.

What should I do?

Comment: I am truly sorry, but I really need to post this link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I wanted to post it but figured I'd try to help him instead of showing him how futile it is to try ;)...

Comment: Yes, posting an actually helpful answer would have been better. Didn't do much html parsing code though (but would perhaps suggest looking into Html Agility Pack which seem to popup as a good html parsing library every now and then: http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

Comment: It ended up being much much easier to just parse the HTML than to use HTML Agility Pack, I had actually looked at Agility before trying Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly: DON'T USE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS TO PARSE HTML. USE AN HTML PARSER.

Secondly: if you really want to do this (and you don't) then instead of \w you could match any character apart from '<':

```
<a href="/userinfo/userinfo\.aspx\?ID=\d*" target="helgonmain">[^<]*</a> \w\d\d
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a character class which specifically includes those things:

```
[\wåäöÅÄÖ]*
```

Or you can use the Unicode character class for letters:

```
\p{L}
```

or specifically for Latin:

```
\p{InBasicLatin}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\p{L}` to match any 'letter', which will support all letters in all languages, as suggested in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656157/regular-expression-to-catch-letters-beyond-a-z).

Or, you can simply replace `\w*` with `[^<]*`, to match all characters that are not the opening of an HTML tag.

But as said by others, parsing HTML using regex is [a first step towards insanity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)...