# How can I detect characters that are not in a specific Unicode category?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I use ASP.NET 4 and C#.

I need to apply a RegEx to an RegularExpressionValidator control to NOT allow inserting in a TextBox of charters that are not in certain [Unicode Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx).

Designation:

- UppercaseLetter
- LowercaseLetter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\p{CLASS}` to match unicode character classes:

```
[\p{UppercaseLetter}\p{LowercaseLetter}]
```

See the "Supported Unicode General Categories" and "Supported Named Blocks" sections of the [Character Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx) page on MSDN for a list of supported character classes.

See also this question: [Regular expression to catch letters beyond a-z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656157/regular-expression-to-catch-letters-beyond-a-z)

**Edit:** Keep in mind that this won't work in the browser as I don't think the client implementations of Regex support `/p`.

Comment: @Dan - Yes, yes they are. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done using a RegularExpressionValidator.

An obvious solution would be to [use a CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k.aspx) that checks [Char.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getunicodecategory.aspx).