# Regular expression matching a given structure

Tags: c#, regex

I need to generate a regex to match any string with this structure:

`{"anyWord"}{"aSpace"}{"-"}{"anyLetter"}`

How can I do it?

Thanks

> EDIT

I have tried:

```
  string txt="print -c";

  string re1="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";   // Word 1

  Regex r = new Regex(re1,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
  Match m = r.Match(txt);
  if (m.Success)
  {
        String word1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
        Console.Write("("+word1.ToString()+")"+"\n");
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
```

but this only matches the word "print"

Comment: As to the problem: Your regex says "match a word", which it does. If you want to match more you will have to express it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be pretty straight-forward :

```
[a-zA-Z]+\s\-[a-zA-Z]
```

explained as follows :

```
[a-zA-Z]+        # Matches 1 or more letters
\s               # Matches a single space
\-               # Matches a single hyphen / dash
[a-zA-Z]         # Matches a single letter
```

If you needed to implement this in C#, you could just use the [`Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) class and specifically the [`Regex.Matches()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(yourString,@"[a-zA-Z]+\s\-[a-zA-Z]");
```

Some example matching might look like this :

[image]

Comment: Looking at the OP's name I can imagine that he is interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656157/regular-expression-to-catch-letters-beyond-a-z. Because he may want to match strings like "Benoîs-à".

Comment: @AgapwIesu Just because the question is deemed poor doesn't mean it shouldn't be answered and definitely isn't a reason to down vote an answer.

Comment: @juharr - answering questions like this encourages this sort of behavior.  Rather, a comment should be added telling the OP to show what he has tried, to demonstrate some basic knowledge of the topic.  As I understood it, SO is not a tutorial site for people to learn **basic** programming concepts but a place where programmers go to help each other with problems.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I'm not defending the OP or the question, just any SO user's prerogative to answer such a question if they so desire.

Comment: @juharr - you are still missing the point that answering questions like this encourages this sort of behavior

Comment: @Agapwlesu I had just posted the question and 30 seconds after you guys flooded the comments section with this sort of remarks. Probably if you would just give me the time to edit or simply asked me what I did try before asking this question, I would have told you. If you check my edit I have given one of my last attempts in answering the question myself before posting. HAPPY?

Comment: @AgapwIesu - Do not badger people providing helpful answers to questions you do not like. Attacking subject matter experts for trying to be helpful will only drive them away, and will not impact in the least the number of people asking lower-quality questions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255861/19679

Comment: @BradLarson I understand your argument and don't want to draw out an OT discussion here; but I would hope that we have fewer low-qual questions if we don't promptly answer them (it's easily to see how a whole CS101 ends up asking for homework here if one student succeeds -- or not, if not). I agree that we shouldn't down-vote correct answers though, but chiding is ok imo.

Comment: @BradLarson, I disagree with your post on meta, but as this points out, this has morphed into more of a meta question.  Will go to your answer there to comment on what I believe you are missing.