# Regex with invariant culture

Tags: c#, string

It seems RegexOptions.CultureInvariant does not work.

```
var match = Regex.Match("välue", @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
//match.Success is flase!!!
```

I'm trying to match all alphanumeric strings in different cultures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow only letters and "special" letters (éèà etc.) through a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131632/allow-only-letters-and-special-letters-%c3%a9%c3%a8%c3%a0-etc-through-a-regex)

Comment: Accented letters are not within the `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]` range.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will helps someone.

```
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("välueÇöıÜ_-", @"^[\p{L}0-9_-]+$", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

\p{L} matches any letters.

[You may also look.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/656177/1068246)